# How to repair mysql tables using myisam storage engine from multiple repairing threads?

Tags: mysql, myisam

I am loading a csv file into a mysql database table that uses MyISAM as storage engine. From the process list I can see that this is accomplished in two phases: 1) reading the csv file and 2) repairing the indexes by sorting.
FYI, I have kept the indexing to **enabled** as it was by defult.

Although I am setting **myisam_repair_threads** to **2** I think mysql is not taking this into count as `show processlist` shows only one entry in the process list. Also, it takes a little bit of time interval before starting repairing, why?

Please correct my understanding if I am wrong! Why mysql is repairing the tables with only one thread although I have set it to 2? Is there anything I am getting wrong about repairing strategy? TIA!

Comment: Why `REPAIR`?  Indexes are usually built on the fly.  Repairing is only needed after a crash.

Comment: @RickJames - if you keep motoring the process list (using `show processlist`) it will show you the query progress in these two phases that i have mentioned above

Comment: Reading the csv -- in app code?  using LOAD DATA?  loading as ENGINE=CSV?

Comment: from mysql cli, and yes, using LOAD DATA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read carefully:

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Server System Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_myisam_repair_threads)

> If this value is greater than 1, MyISAM table indexes are created in parallel (**each index in its own thread**) during the Repair by sorting process.

If your table have 2 indices - then 2 threads will (must) be used.

PS. I'm not sure that you will see this in processlist... this has to be checked.

Comment: and what about the repairing starting after a bit of pause? any idea?

Comment: @mghh - How many indexes does the table have?  Multiple threads are used only if you multiple indexes.

Comment: And that _may_ apply only to "Repair by sorting" (versus using the key_buffer).

Comment: @RickJames - the table has 11 indexes, one of which is a composite one

Comment: @Akina is correct about repairing thread count, but i can't find out the reason behind the repairing being initiated after a bit of interval.